# Django Test Login Failing

Tags: python, django, testing, authentication

I am trying to do some simple testing with Django but I can't successfully login with the user. Here is my code:

```
def createUser(isadmin):
    u = User.objects.create_user(username="Test" + ("Admin" if isadmin else "Regular"), password="test")
    return u

def loginUser(self, theusername, thepassword):

    print(theusername + " " + thepassword)
    a = self.client.login(username = theusername, password = thepassword)
    # Prints false - should be true, right?
    print(a)
```

The somewhere later:

```
class DailyEntriesIntTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        u = createUser(False)
        loginUser(self, u.username, u.password)
```

Shouldn't that be all I need to login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops - the password was encrypted - I need to pass in the plaintext password and then the method correctly returns "true".